# How to ignore struct declarations and consider only definitions in cscope?

Tags: vim, cscope

I always use vim + cscope to check symbol definition, and I find cscope always take declaration like:

```
struct sk_buff;
```

as a definition, which make vim always show a long list files to choose. Indeed, I only want the definition:

```
struct sk_buff {
  ...
};
```

Seems ctags can resolve this problem, but can cscope handle this? Or somethings I'm wrong.

I checked the cscope source, and I find it's hard to modify the lex and yacc source from beginning.

Comment: Add a lex rule to the source of cscope(fscanner.l) to ignore such kind of definition, now it's okay.

Also found that cscope has many places to improve, or it is not suitable for big project's source browsing.

Comment: Arghhh, why can it not do it?! It can already do it for functions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, you cannot do this just with cscope.
I use cscope+ctags with vim every day on both small and large projects as well.
I've found the most productive way to use these tools is to use them both from within vim and with the cscope_maps.vim plugin.

This may not help you but it's helped me int he past, check [this site](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html) for information on using them together.  I'll warn you that if you use the **cscope_maps.vim plugin** you'll probably want to edit it and comment out the **"set cscopetag"** option.